# Nosetests + allure causes duplicated tests cases if test folder contains __init__.py

Tags: python, nose, allure

I have following project structure:

[image: Project structure]

***runner.py*** file contains:

```
import nose

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.main(argv=['-v', "some_folder/", "--with-allure", "--logdir=D:\Reports"])
```

**The problem:** After execution, I go to given *logdir* and see 3 xml files (2 of them are identical), which causes duplicates in the generated allure report:
[image: As you can see, the test2.py contains only two tests, but they are duplicated]

Seems like duplication is caused by ***__init__.py*** file, because if I move ***test2.py*** to the same folder as ***test1.py*** I don't face such problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is known [issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-nose/issues/6). Please track it, I hope this will be fixed.